# printers.conf saves password in plain text - encryption?

Tags: printing, configuration, password

Is it possible to change the printers.conf so that the password isn't shown as plain text there?

We're using a global printing solution where the domain users have to authenticate to print - if they save the password it will be saved as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use encryptfs to have any text-based config file encrypted and decyphered in memory when user logins. It is used mostly for encrypting whole /home folder, but you can tweak that. Read guides on it's setup.